# Getting the jQuery object that has been clicked on in angular via $event

Tags: angularjs

I have a list like this.  It is pre rendered and so cannot make use of anything attached to ng-repeat.

```
<li ng-class="{ 'active': 1 == selectedIndex }">
    <a href="" ng-clicked="itemClicked($event)">Item 1</a>
</li>
```

I want to be able to toggle the class of the `<li>` when the `a` is clicked.

Looking at some other answers to similar questions on here, it seems as though there is a variable associated with ng-repeat which means you can use an `$index` variable to achieve this.  As this list is pre-rendered this is not available and so I guess I have to do it the jQuery way.

I see that I have access to an $event object but event.target only gives me the DOM element, I would like to be able to convert it into a jQuery object.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You have to think about this in a different way than you would normally.  You can't modify the DOM within angular like you do with plain old jquery.  Here is what you should do:

```
<li ng-class="{ active: selectedItem == item }" ng-repeat="item in list">
   <a href="javascript://" ng-clicked="itemSelected( item )">{{ item.name }}</a>
</li>
```

Then in your controller:

```
$scope.selectedItem = null; // if this is loaded from a service then you can set it after it loads.
$scope.itemSelected = function( item ) {
   $scope.selectedItem = item;
}
```

No need to play around with indexes, jquery, or one off code.

Charlie

Comment: I get the following error when doing this:
Error: 'item' in 'item in collection' should be identifier or (key, value) but got '{item'.

My understanding that ng-repeat was specifically for rendering a series of elements .  I was not aware that you could use it to iterate through lists that already exist.

Comment: `ng-repeat="{item in list }"` should be `ng-repeat="item in list"`

Comment: Yes dnc is right.  I typed this out quickly and repeated the same notation in ng-class accidentally.  I've fixed the code sample now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it is still not working though.  The <Lli> are no longer there.  Instead where there used to be <li>Item<li> it is now simply <!-- ngRepeat:item in list -->.  Note that I am not using the {{ item.name }} part of your code as the list is not being generated by angular.

Comment: Should say though that the error is gone after your amended code.